# Use docker image as runtime for Java function

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, serverless

We are trying to deploy a Java Lambda function in AWS using a image container runtime.
We are building the image with Maven and the image building is happening with the serverless framework.
As the base image we are using the AWS Java 11 base image:
https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-base-images/blob/java11/Dockerfile.java11

For the runtime image for our lambda we have the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/java:11


# https://gallery.ecr.aws/lambda/java
# https://hub.docker.com/r/amazon/aws-lambda-java
# Copy function code and runtime dependencies from Maven layout
COPY target/classes ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}
COPY target/dependency/* ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}/lib/
COPY target/or-tools/ortools-linux-x86-64/* ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}/lib/ortools-linux-x86-64/

# Set the CMD to your handler
CMD ["com.visma.omed.serverless.Handler::handleRequest"]
```

When building the image locally with docker build -t java-test . we can succesfully test the lambda locally and see that the image builds correctly.
But when we are building the image with serverless we can see that the files are copied correctly but all the ENV variables from Base image has dissapeared. When calling the lambda in aws we receive the following error:
Error: Couldn't find valid bootstrap(s): []"

Serverless configuration looks the following way:

```
ecr:
    images:
      java_handler:
        path: ./src/Java-handlers/
        file: Dockerfile
```

What could be the issue? Can provide additional information if necessary

Have tried multiple different approaches. For example building the image from our Dockerfile manually and referencing it in our Serverless configuration, works as expected.